# Trigger that delete a value before or after inserting a matching statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-delete, database-trigger

So I am working on a college project, and in my database I need to delete a boss before or after, it doesnt matter, when inserting a boss that match the same department, but I keep getting the mutating table error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PRUEBA3
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MODERADORES
COMPOUND TRIGGER

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    IF departamento==:NEW.departamento THEN

        DELETE FROM MODERADORES WHERE OID_MOD = old_moderador;

    END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

END PRUEBA3;
/
```

Comment: I would suggest that you use `merge` rather than `insert`, if that is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Why do you want to use a Trigger? What you are probably looking for is to have a unique row for a department in your table. A *Unique constraint* is typically used for that purpose, or better a Primary Key. Explore how these things work before jumping to use a Trigger for everything.

Comment: The point of a compound trigger is to store details of the amended records (usually in an array) in a BEFORE (or AFTER) EACH ROW section then use that array to do something in the AFTER STATEMENT section. In your case you would stash the department ID and ID of the new boss in the array then look up and delete the old bosses all at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to delete the boss on Insert So remove the delete trigger. This will remove the Mutating trigger.

```
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON MODERADORES
```

but for Insert how you will match the old value. Best solution is to use the Merge statement where you are trying to do the same